# Implement Roll-backing in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, debian, shell-script, apt

I have implemented an Ubuntu package in which bash scripts are using.
I followed these for making packages in Ubuntu.

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/27715/create-a-deb-package-from-scripts-or-binaries/27731#27731
- http://odzangba.wordpress.com/2006/10/13/how-to-build-local-apt-repositories/

But I want to know how to implement roll backing in bash script if execution fails in between. Now even if the package installation(sudo apt-get install package-name) fails in between, it will show the 'The newest version already installed' in the second attempt.

Comment: If `sudo apt-get install package-name` fails at apt level, nothing was done. If it fails at `dpkg` then something was done ;).

Comment: Actually it was not an actual fail. What I mean that, during the package installation with apt-get, my bash script prompts for a confirmation `yes/no?`. If we choose 'no' the installation will stop there. But the next time when trying `apt-get install package-name` it will show `newest package has already installed`. Could you give me a good tutorial for package management in Ubuntu ?